# $.when.apply on array of deferreds runs before all resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to build a prerequisite chain for some classes. Because of unknown recursion depth, I have an ajax call which runs every time a new course is created. `DFDS` is a global array to store deferreds in. `COURSES` is a global array of courses.

```
var DFDS = []; //define global DFDS
var course = function( options ) {
  ...
  var self = this;
  this.p = { //prereqs object
    a: [], // array for prereqs
    rgx: /([A-Z]\w+[\ ])\w+/g, 
    parse: function() {
      if (self.prereqs == '') return true;
      self.prereqs.replace(this.rgx,function(m) {
        //search through prereq string (self.prereqs) and run ajax for each match
        var id = m.split(' ');
        var dfd2 = $.Deferred();
        DFDS.push(dfd2);
        $.getJSON('/ajax/ajaxPrereqs.php',{subj:id[0],crs:id[1]},function(d) {
          var d = d[0];
          self.p.a.push(new course({
            ... //create new course in self.p.a[]
          }));
          dfd2.resolve();
        });
      });
    }
  };
  ...
  //run parse function when created
  this.p.parse();
  return this;
}
```

I'm able to get the structure I expect with all the right courses loaded into all the right `self.p.a[]` arrays.

So to initialize the top-level courses:

```
$.getJSON('/ajax/ajaxPrereqs.php',{subj:$('#subj').val()}, function(data) {

  $.each(data,function() {
    var d = this;
    COURSES.push(new course({
      s: d.subj,
      c: d.crs,
      t: d.titleshrt,
      crd: d.credits,
      chr: d.contacthrs,
      prereqs: d.prereqs
    }));
  });


  console.log(DFDS.length); //displays 10
  $.when.apply($, DFDS).then(function() {
    console.log('DFDS all done???');
    console.log(DFDS.length);
    $.each(DFDS,function() {console.log(this.state())})
    $.each(COURSES,function() {
      this.render();
    })
  });

});
```

PROBLEM: `$.when.apply` is running BEFORE all deferreds resolve. My console says:

```
24
(10) resolved
(14) pending
```

I also tried running this logging function every 5 milliseconds:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log('--- intv ---');
  var pending = 0;
  var resolved = 0;
  $.each(DFDS,function() {
    switch(this.state()) {
      case 'pending': pending++; break;
      case 'resolved': resolved++; break;
      default: console.log('NOT PENDING OR RESOLVED');
    }
  });
  console.log(pending+' pending');
  console.log(resolved+' resolved');
},5);
```

The last console entry right before `$.when.apply` runs is 14 pending, 8 resolved.

There are 92 ajax calls when this completes. All 92 return good data (no errors / fails).

How can I tell it to run `.then()` after all DFDs in array (not just ones in array when `$.when.apply` defined?)

Comment: Can you show the whole calling sequence.  We need to see where you define `DFDS`, call the `parse()` method and where in the sequence you call `$.when.apply($, DFDS)` and so on.  You're only showing us pieces and the problem is likely in how the pieces fit together.  Also, you're using an anti-pattern in creating a new deferred rather than just using the one that `$.getJSON()` returns.

Comment: see edit. I tried both using the anti-pattern (as specified above) and using the deferred from `$.getJSON()` and neither changed the result

Comment: create demo that replicates this. Should be able to check `arguments` length in `$when` callback if you use the ajax deffered. The one you use has no data in resolve

Comment: I see one conceptual problem.  Because you have nested Ajax calls (you call `new course()` inside of `$.getJSON()` which can in turn call `$.getJSON()` more times) that all add items to `DFDS`, you're calling `$.when.apply(DFDS)` before you've necessarily even finished building the `DFDS` array.

Comment: @jfriend00 right - I realized that and added it to the question via edit - I won't know how long `DFDS` is before all the ajax calls complete... that's basically the problem. any ideas on a solution there?

Comment: A solution would be to use chained promises so the top level promise won't resolve until all embedded requests are resolved too.  In all honestly, your code is so hard to follow that I'm having a hard time proposing a fix without a major restructuring. The whole concept of accumulating promises in a global variable is repugnant to me.  I'll think about it.  Plus triggering multiple Ajax calls from a constructor rules out the usual ways that you return promises that tell you when async operations are done.  It's messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general idea.  I had several goals here.

1. Get rid of the global variable that you were accumulating promises into.
2. Make all nested promises be chained onto their parent promises so that you can just wait on the parent promises and everything will just work.
3. To chain promises, I replace the completion callback in `$.getJSON()` with a `.then()` handler and then return the embedded promises from the `.then()` handler.  This automatically chains them onto the parent so the parent won't itself get resolved until the embedded ones are also resolved.  And, this works to an arbitrary depth of embedded promises.
4. Get rid of the anti-pattern of creating and resolving new deffereds when promises already exist that can just be used.

In the process of getting rid of the globals, I had to remove the creation of promises from the `course` constructor because it can't return the promises.  So, I created a `course.init()` where the promises are created and returned.  Then, we can accumulate promises in a local variable and avoid the global.

So, here's the general idea:

```
var course = function( options ) {
  ...
  var self = this;

  this.p = { //prereqs object
    a: [], // array for prereqs
    rgx: /([A-Z]\w+[\ ])\w+/g, 
    parse: function() {
      var promises = [];
      // check if we have any prereqs to process
      if (self.prereqs !== '') {
          self.prereqs.replace(this.rgx,function(m) {
            //search through prereq string (self.prereqs) and run ajax for each match
            var id = m.split(' ');
            promises.push($.getJSON('/ajax/ajaxPrereqs.php',{subj:id[0],crs:id[1]}).then(function(d) {
              var d = d[0];
              var c = new course({
                ... //create new course in self.p.a[]
              }));
              self.p.a.push(c);
              // chain all the new promises created by c.init() onto our master promise
              // by returning a new promise from the .then() handler
              return(c.init());
            }));        
          });
      }
      // return a master promise that is resolve when all the sub promises 
      // created here are all done
      return $.when.apply($, promises);
    }
  };

  // call this to run the initial parse
  // returns a single promise that is resolve when all the promises are done
  this.init = function() {
      return this.p.parse();
  };

  ...
  return this;
}

$.getJSON('/ajax/ajaxPrereqs.php',{subj:$('#subj').val()}, function(data) {

  var promises = [];
  var COURSES = [];
  $.each(data,function() {
    var d = this;
    var c = new course({
      s: d.subj,
      c: d.crs,
      t: d.titleshrt,
      crd: d.credits,
      chr: d.contacthrs,
      prereqs: d.prereqs
    });
    COURSES.push(c);
    promises.push(c.init());    
  });
  $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    console.log('promises all done');
    console.log(promises.length);
    $.each(promises,function() {console.log(this.state())})
    $.each(COURSES,function() {
      this.render();
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked. I appreciate everyone's comments. It helped me realize the issue was `$.when.apply` was watching only the deferreds in `DFDS` when `$.when.apply` was defined.

I put this function in the `$.getJSON` callback in course constructor `.parse()`.

```
function checkDFDS() {
  var completed = 0;
  $.each(DFDS,function() {
    if (this.state()=='resolved') completed++;
  });
  if (completed == DFDS.length) {
    $.each(COURSES,function() {
      this.render();
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Proper use of chained promises would not require managing all this yourself.

Comment: @jfriend00 - What would be the proper use?

Comment: Chaining the embedded promises onto the parent promises.  Then, you can do `$.when()` on just the parent promises and it will all work.  Unfortunately, the structure of your code makes this impossible, so your code would have to be restructured so you aren't creating promises created in `new course()` and stuffing them into a global, but rather they can be returned and chained onto the parent promise with `.then()`.